# Get value from specific row

Tags: c#

I am trying to fetch a specific value from the following query:

```
 var query = from a in db.Questions
        where a.CategoryId == 1
        select a;
```

Essentially I want to get an integer in the result in the 3rd row of the following query in 'a.questionId' and cast it to an interger. I imagine its something like:

```
int qNum = query.single(Row 3).questionId;
```

Comment: Your query is returning all questions of a specific category, but it is difficult to understand what you are after given it isn't clear how a row figures into your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try:

```
int qNum = query.Skip(2).First().questionId;
```

Comment: The fastest gun in the west.

Comment: you first need to `OrderByDescending` of `questionId`

Comment: @Omribitan - That's only if the OP wants the results ordered first. It's never stated that the 3rd row is the 3rd of any specific order.

Comment: @JustinNiessner Technically you are right, I just assumed that the 3rd row meant the 3rd question so ...

Answer (score 1):

```
int qNum = query.Skip(2).First().questionId;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int qNum = query.Skip(2).First().questionId;
```